# Rails, postgres, timezones, and ActiveRecord order method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, timezone, rails-postgresql

I have a query that orders a group of tasks by their start_date(UTC datetime).

This works perfectly.

The problem comes when displaying the ordered records for the end user in their timezone.

lets say I have 5 tasks (ordered by their utc times)

1 2:00

2 3:00

3 12:00

4 16:00

5 22:00

This is the correct order.

But when I convert to EDT:

1 22:00

2 23:00

4 12:00

5 18:00

Is there a way to specify the timezone you're querying in postgres using activerecord?

Thank you

Comment: So you want to convert your timestamps to a specific time zone then extract the time of day (in that time zone of course) and then sort that?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have the results sorted from the database, which would require converting them to a time zone. Off to the postgres docs.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I did not - because of how few results I was pulling from the DB, I simply pulled the results and then sorted them in ruby.